# Остановить отправку формы jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Есть форма:

```
<form action='https://loans-qa.ru/api/create' method='post'>
    <input />
    <input />
<button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return goPrice()">
    Купить в кредит</button>
</form>
```

Есть JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function goPrice(){ 
        if(jQuery('html').hasClass('out-of-stock') ) {
            alert('Данного товара нет в наличии!'); 
    }
    else { 
        var cena;
        cena = jQuery("div.woocommerce-variation-price span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").html().split('<')[0].replace('&nbsp;', '');
        jQuery( "input[name$='itemPrice_0']" ).val(cena);
        jQuery( "input[name$='sum']" ).val(cena);
        return true;
    }
};
</script>
```

Если на странице есть класс `out-of-stock` - остановить переход и выдать сообщение.
Если данного класса нет - выполнить:

```
var cena;
        cena = jQuery("div.woocommerce-variation-price span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").html().split('<')[0].replace('&nbsp;', '');
        jQuery( "input[name$='itemPrice_0']" ).val(cena);
        jQuery( "input[name$='sum']" ).val(cena);
        return true;
```

Как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function goPrice() {
  if (jQuery('.out-of-stock').length) {
    alert('Данного товара нет в наличии!');
    return false; // !!!
  } else {
    var cena;
    cena = jQuery("div.woocommerce-variation-price span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").html().split('<')[0].replace('&nbsp;', '');
    jQuery("input[name$='itemPrice_0']").val(cena);
    jQuery("input[name$='sum']").val(cena);
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Я так пробовал и к сожалению, данный вариант не работает... ( В случае присутствия данного класса, форма не останавливается и переходит на action все равно. А если класса нет, то скрипт после else не выполнятся. ((((

Comment: @Brodjga1095 `if (jQuery('.out-of-stock').length) {`

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Все заработало! Но только я понять не могу... Почему не работало с hasClass?

Comment: @Brodjga1095 Потому что `if (jQuery('.out-of-stock').length) {` проверяет наличие элементов с классом `out-of-stock` на странице, а `if(jQuery('html').hasClass('out-of-stock') ) {` проверяет наличие класса `out-of-stock` у тега `html`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Без Вас я наверное не разобрался! Еще раз спасибо!